# Cytoscape - apps installed but not showing

Tags: cytoscape

I have successfully installed Cytoscape.

```
Version: 3.8.2 
Java: 11.0.6 by AdoptOpenJDK 
Java Home: /Applications/Cytoscape_v3.8.2/.install4j/jre.bundle/Contents/Home 
OS: Mac OS X 10.15.6 - x86_64
```

I have successfully installed several apps.

[image]

However, only one of the apps *JGF App* shows in App drop down menu, none of the other apps seem present/active.  For example, *gexf-app* should allow Cytoscape to import that format of file but neither 'File/Open' or 'File Import' recognize the file type.

Having read the docs, many file types are supported (seemingly) for import.  However I have had no success in importing files which is arguably the most important to me at the moment.

How can I make the installed apps work or what may be preventing them from doing so?

Note: I this unanswered [stackexchange question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/how-to-activate-an-installed-plugin-networkanalyzer-on-cytoscape) seems related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to hear about your issues.  My guess is that one of the apps you installed is crashing on startup and preventing the other apps from starting.  I would start by disabling "JGF App" and "gexf-app" and see if the other apps all come up.  Looking at the list of apps, you won't see them in the apps menu, though -- look in the tools menu for "Merge" and "Analyze Network".  Then, you can enable gexf-app and see if it starts up (if it doesn't, you should see an indicator in the lower left-hand corner of Cytoscape).  If you click it, it will give you a little more information about what happened.  If that starts up fine, you can try to enable "JGF App".

-- scooter